How make Global import for HTML element for vanilla js
Hello im learning web devlopment and i want to make a global imports for dynamically button usage cause if i make a
const button = document.createElement('button') as HTMLButtonElement

it will use fone one page. Im still learning how do it. Thanks
Get a global import for button dynamically thank you

export const button - ......   then import {button} from "./globalfns"

Just a side note -> as HTMLButtonElement  this is not needed, Typescript can easily infer the type for you.
